# Where is CiviPetition currently documented please?

Tags: activities

My online searches for CiviPetition guidance have so far found only nine year old articles which lead to dead ends?  Is petition functionality still supported in the latest version of CiviCRM?  Can someone here please point me to online guidance for how to use it?  Thanks.  -- Hugh

Comment: There are some docs at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/petition/what-is-civipetition/ and more pages if you look in the left sidebar there.

Comment: @Demerit this should be an answer and not a comment, don't you think? I was going to answer exactly the same by pointing to the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are some docs at docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/petition/what-is-civipetition and more pages if you look in the left sidebar there.